# According to PEP-8, how can I write my function signature properly?

Tags: python, pep8, type-hinting

I've stumbled across this function header:

```
# version 1
def schedule_single_scoring(submission: Submission,
                            scoring_specification: ScoringSpecification
                            ) -> SubmissionScore:
```

I do not like that the last line starts with the closing paranthesis but I haven't found an argument against it in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), maybe I've overseen it.

My question is: Is it legitimate to write the code as in *version 1*? Or  should it be something like this:

```
# version 2
def schedule_single_scoring(
    submission: Submission,
    scoring_specification: ScoringSpecification) -> SubmissionScore:
    """multiline docstrings are present"""

# version 3
def schedule_single_scoring(submission: Submission, scoring_specification:
        ScoringSpecification) -> SubmissionScore:
```

I would prefer *version 3* but I do not want to rewrite the code if it's simply not against coding guidelines.

Comment: Use version 1 but delete one space from the line so the `)` lines-up with the opening `(`—in other words it's fine to have a line that starts with a closing parenthesis in this situation. PEP-8 are just guidelines, so for cases it doesn't specifically address, just do something that results in what you think is the most readable code.

Comment: A lot of the open source world is moving to [black](https://github.com/ambv/black).

Comment: Very interesting link, @wim . Thanks for sharing! :)